# Azure app service - Do I need Vnet integration on both svc plan and app svc?

Tags: azure, service, web-applications, terraform

I have a requirement to use VNET integration on all resources but it seems if I already have it in app-svc it don't need to specify it at the app service plan level.
Is there is anything I'm missing here? The webapps work fine but I'm thinking that perhaps I'm missing something by not specifying vnet integration in the service plan.
This would help avoiding the extra work of creating new integrations zones for each app service deployed, as you know the relationship is one to one for svc-plans and integration subnets delegated to the service.

Answer (score 3):

VNet integration is being done through the application settings of an `App Service`, not through the `App plans`.

If you want to route all of your outbound traffic into your VNet, apply the app setting `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` to your app services.

Detailed information can be found [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/app-service-web-vnet-regional.md).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the @adp answer: the app setting `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` is now deprecated. This should be set on the `Networking` blade of the app service, by going to `VNet integration`. Once the integration is turned on, it will be possible to activate this setting, as in the screenshot below.

[image]